# MVC: how do reference an input tag in a view, from a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this is my first experienc with MVC. i am followinf a tutorial and i have checked and rechecked that i have followed the steps correctly, but some code in the controller is trying to reference and input tag in the view, to check if the check box was selected. and it is generating an error "the name check_public does not exist in the current context"

i have a view called "index.cshtml" which contains the following code:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="check_public" /> <br />
```

and i have a Controller which is trying to reference that checkbox by name, the code is

```
     if (check_public != null) 
        { 
            dbList.Public = "YES"; 
        }
     else 
        { 
            dbList.Public = "NO"; 
        }
```

its probably something obvious and simple but i am really stuck. any help is appreciated

Comment: Where in your controller have your declared and initialized `check_public`? You need to get it from the `Request`

Comment: I think you don't have `check_public` with `bool?` type on controller action method.

Comment: ah, so if i declare it with a bool? type in the action method how do i make it check the status of the checkbox in the view?

Comment: @LucyViolet You can use viewmodel class containing `bool? check_public` property, and `CheckBoxFor` to bind it into controller action. Or use `BindAttribute` then mention your checkbox input in `Include` part.

Comment: thanks this should help me make some progress.

Comment: Please see the below link [pass checkbox value to ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862712/pass-values-of-checkbox-to-controller-action-in-asp-net-mvc4)

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve this by declaring the variable *check_public* by adding the below line above the if statement in the controller

```
      string check_public = Request.Form["check_public"];
```