# how to get checkbox property to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

i have a checkbox that are checked based on the value from my xml but how do i then get the value from the view to the controller

my view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Settings", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    foreach (SettingsModel setting in Model)
    {
    <input @(Convert.ToBoolean(setting.GSuccess)==true ? "checked='checked'" : string.Empty) type="checkbox" /></td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Gem", "", null, new { @id = "submit" })
    }

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                document.forms[0].submit();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

my action result

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), ActionName("Settings")]
            public ActionResult Save(SettingsModel setting)
            {
                Boolean gSuccess = setting.GSuccess;

                List<SettingsModel> settings = new List<SettingsModel>();
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XML/Settings.xml"));
                foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/Settings/UserSettings"))
                {
                    settings.Add(new SettingsModel
                    {
                        GSuccess = Boolean.Parse(node["GSuccess"].InnerText)
 });
                doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/XML/Settings.xml"));
            }
                return RedirectToAction("Settings", "Home");
            ;
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: plz show your form in the razor file?

Comment: You checkbox does not even have a `name` or `value` attribute (it wont post anything, and it does not bind to anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna pass a value to the controller you can make it more simple with the html helper and it works with your checked value aswell

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => setting.GSuccess)
```

Answer (score 1):

If a checkbox is checked, then the postback values will contain a key-value pairs.

In your razor, add a name for the check box list:

```
<input @(Convert.ToBoolean(setting.GSuccess)==true ? "checked='checked'" : string.Empty) 
type="checkbox" name="nameOfYourCheckboxList" /></td>
```

In your controller use the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(FormCollection collection)
{
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["nameOfYourCheckboxList"])
     {
         //do whatever you need here       
     }
}
```

Alternative solutions: [1](http://www.gunaatita.com/Blog/Send-multiple-checkbox-values-from-view-to-controller-in-MVC/1047) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862712/pass-values-of-checkbox-to-controller-action-in-asp-net-mvc4/18863351).